# Can this sentence have two meanings?

Tags: grammar, sentence

> Behavior dubbed reprehensible by the residents of the region is considered conventional, even compulsory by those of the neighboring region; fortunately, people traveling between the two are resigned to this disparity.

Can it mean that the behavior dubbed reprehensible is considered conventional 'generally' and compulsory by those of the neighboring region?

Or can it only mean that the 'neighboring region' consider it conventional and even compulsory?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking, your alternatives seem to be restatements of the same condition. What I think you are asking is whether residents of other regions, or perhaps the world in general, share the views of the inhabitants of one or the other region on the reprehensibility of the behaviour. Am I right?

Comment: You may not be aware that _dubbed_ means _called, described as_. Your phrase 'the reprehensible dubbed behaviour' doesn't make sense. One region thinks certain activities are perfectly acceptable, another calls them reprehensible.

Comment: 'Behavior dubbed reprehensible by the residents of the region is considered conventional (generally or by the world), even (considered) compulsory by the neighboring region.' Can this sentence be interpreted like this? I mean can 'considered conventional' mean that it is generally thought to be conventional by the world, or is just that the neighboring region consider it conventional and compulsory at the same time

Comment: Your second option is right. Nothing is said about the world in general.

Comment: I suspect it could be expressed and punctuated better, but there's definitely ambiguity. Compare "Taylor Swift is considered a megastar, even an object of veneration to some fans" - here the punctuation isn't great but "considered a megastar" is a general opinion while her being "an object of veneration" is more narrowly applied. You could say "widely considered X, and Y to a small group" to make it clearer if the two have different range, or "considered X and even Y" if both apply to the same group.

Comment: @StuartF: I disagree. Your Taylor Swift example is the same as OP's here. That's to say, *neither* of them say anything at all about what "the world in general" might think. Fairly obviously Taylor Swift would only really be considered a megastar by her fans (I'm sure *most* people across the entire world have no idea who she is! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Have you heard of the sun? What would you understand by this: "The sun is considered a necessity of life, even revered as a God by some cultures."  (or if you prefer "The sun is considered a necessity of life, even a God by some cultures." ) Does that mean water is only considered a necessity of life to some cultures? It's common, although not good grammar, to put almost any kind of subsidiary information on the end of a sentence joined by a comma, and English allows wide latitude in ellipsis.

Comment: ... Or "The sun is found to be hot, even fatally hot for some people."

Comment: @StuartF Oh okay. I see now that I'm ignoring the orthographic significance of the pause/comma that *could* appear before ***by** [some people]*. How to interpret it simply depends on whether just ***even revered as a God*** (in your example) is seen as an optional parenthetical element (set off by commas / pauses). In the written form *without* that second comma, we should in principle assume that ***by some cultures*** refers back to ***both*** preceding clauses, not just the second one. But people will often mispunctuate anyway, and you *might* not be able to detect the spoken pauses accura

Comment: _Behavior dubbed reprehensible by the residents of the region is considered conventional, even compulsory, by those of the neighboring region; fortunately, people traveling between the two are resigned to this disparity._ // I can't see the 'considered conventional' having any other noun group to sensibly attach to other than 'those of the surrounding region', and the added comma is necessary. 'This disparity' must also be between the two regions. No third party is mentioned, so by Gricean maxims, the obvious ones must be inferred.